# Calculate Fiscal Quarter start date based on given date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm having trouble determining the right way to pull the fiscal quarter start dates (in M/D/YYYY format) based on given dates.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qIc5wk4o_JLhfV60AxI7fzdAS2cuVhyPX4Ll0KZrrgo/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample Google Sheet with an outline of what a fiscal year looks like as well as sample dates and desired output.

No matter the year, Q1 always starts Feb 1, Q2 starts May 1, Q3 starts Aug 1, Q4 starts Nov 1.

I'm able to pull the FY & quarter from a date but haven't figured out how to pull the quarter start date from a date without making a big lookup table.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,sequence(95,1,E3,-1),
     max(filter(Σ,day(Σ)=1,xmatch(month(Σ),{2,5,8,11}))))
```

[image]

***single array-style formula:***

```js
=map(E3:E,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,let(Σ,sequence(95,1,Σ,-1),
     max(filter(Σ,day(Σ)=1,xmatch(month(Σ),{2,5,8,11})))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out which seems to work but still wondering if there is a simpler solution - solution is assuming the provided date is in cell E3:

```
=IF(OR(MONTH(E3)=2,MONTH(E3)=3,MONTH(E3)=4),TO_DATE(2&"/"&1&"/"&YEAR(E3)),
IF(OR(MONTH(E3)=5,MONTH(E3)=6,MONTH(E3)=7),TO_DATE(5&"/"&1&"/"&YEAR(E3)),
IF(OR(MONTH(E3)=8,MONTH(E3)=9,MONTH(E3)=10),TO_DATE(8&"/"&1&"/"&YEAR(E3)),
IF(OR(MONTH(E3)=11,MONTH(E3)=12),TO_DATE(11&"/"&1&"/"&YEAR(E3)),
IF(MONTH(E3)=1,TO_DATE(11&"/"&1&"/"&YEAR(E3)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IFNA(
    --(TEXT(VLOOKUP(--TEXT(E3:E15,"m/d"),--TEXT(A2:A6,"m/d"),1),"m/d/")&
       TEXT(E3:E15,"y"))))
```